# Passing variable locations (as integers) from a jframe (as main class) to another class for manipulation

Tags: java

I have a programming professor that would like us to write a Tic Tac Toe game a specific way. He wants us to have the "board" class and have specific mutators within to deal with the data and keep as much info in that class as possible. Specifically, He would like us to have a few methods where the only variable passed is an integer that has to do with the location of a variable. for example:

```
public char getMarkAt(int location) //would return the mark at the given location.
```

Would I be able to have an instantiation of my jframe within this class, and have another class which handled all other work? For example: Have a jframe which was simply my nine boxes and a character array (let's say charArray for simplicity) full of a random character (We'll say 0 for the time being) and then get and set marks from the class by creating an instance of the class JFrame1 (named Picture) doing something like

```
JFrame1 Picture = new JFrame1;    
Picture.charArray[location] = 'X';
```

Or do I have this all wrong? I have been using JFrames as my main class in the past, and he has thrown in these mandatory passed variables to (I believe) keep us from doing so. Sorry for the craziness!

Comment: Your professor is "encouraging" your separate the logic of the UI from the logic of the model/data. You could read about MVC, but basically this is very common paradigm used throughout most language

Comment: Thank you for your reply. after looking at the instructions a bit more and looking at MVC, I think you are right. I will be separating my UI logic and my data. I also have come to the conclusion that the "location" he is speaking of is simply 1-9 on the board, however we intend to interpret that within our method. Would it then be better to store a character array (what I will be using as my storage method for the data at hand) for the game board within my UI logic, or within the class that contains all of my methods?

Comment: Think about it this way, if you wanted to change the implementation to something else, how hard would it be?  For example, you come up with a model which allows for network play?  How hard will it be to update your program?  If you say "hard", then your structure is wrong.  The model should support the data and the management of the data and nothing else, so if you find yourself adding functionality to the model, which really doesn't support the model (and/or makes assumptions about the implementation), then it's wrong

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, it's much like how the String and Integer classes work, in that you can invoke them when necessary, to be used whenever they can. I would put my data within the UI logic, (or should I have yet another class?) and use the Board class to manipulate it? That way the Board class is as versatile as possible, rather than having the sole objective of playing one game of tic-tac-toe.

Comment: You have two basic concepts, you have a "virtual" view, which is the data which represents the state and can allow you to update it and the "physical" view, which is how you represent the "virtual" view and through which the user can manipulate it (through keyboard and mouse), which changes the "virtual" view, which then notifies the "physical" view so it can update itself

Comment: Ok, and the "physical" view is just a reflection of the "virtual" view, the Board class, which is providing the "physical" view with its information.

Comment: Based on what I understand of your problem, yes

Comment: OH. I just re-thought implementing network play and it would be easier to store the data within the Board class as private data and use accessors. Then I can do whatever I want on the physical view side of things to accommodate for changes, say network play implementation. Thanks so much for your help! Still a new student, so even the simplest of things take some thought.

Comment: Hello light bulb moment ;) - The whole thing becomes a lot easier when you introduce interfaces, but the basic concept remains the same ;)

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to start a chat. Is there any way I can give you a "thumbs up" or something for your answer? Will delete after I show you some love.

Comment: Here's an idea, based on your understand of the problem and suggested solution, write your own answer, let me know when your done and if you're on the right track, I'll give you an up-vote ;)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this situation would be to use the "Board" class to handle the data and have a sort of "Virtual" game board. Then use the JFrame specifically to show a physical copy of that virtual board to the user, so that the user may interact with the program. Doing this will allow all of the logic behind "Tic Tac Toe" To be left to the "Board" class, and any logic within the GUI will solely be to allow interaction between the user and the game.